# Unable to install WSL on windows 10 running inside virtual box

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have followed the exact steps of installing WSL on windows 10 guest OS running on virtual Box. 
I installed Ubuntu from Microsoft App store. But when I click on Launch I get the 
following error - 
**WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102** 
**Error: 0x80370102 The virutal machine could not be started because a required feature is

not installed.**
What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: Please provide the output of `wsl --list --verbose`. Also, try running `wsl --set-default-version 1` first.

Comment: wsl --list --verbose  outputs : `windows subsystem for linux has no installed distributions`. when I open Microsoft App store it shows Ubuntu is installed and shows a `Launch` button. But this error is coming when I click on the launch button. Also just mentioning it again - `I am installing WSL on the windows - 10 guest OS inside virtual box`. I found some posts online that virtual box doesn't support WSL

Comment: In one of the youtube videos I tried the command - ` VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "Windows 10" --nested-hw-virt on` and enabled the `Enable PAE/NX and `Enable Nested VT-x/AMD-V` under the processor tab in VB. But still the same error

Comment: WSL _1_ works in VirtualBox because it does not use virtualization. WSL 2 is not compatible.

Comment: Which WSL version are you installing and which "exact steps of installing WSL" have you followed?

Comment: did you find a solution?